# Does Lenovo builtin 3g modem work with debian (network-manager)

Tags: debian, networkmanager, 3g

I'm going to buy laptop similar to this one: [link](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/w-series/w530/index.html) (Lenovo W530), I'm considering buying internal 3G modem: ([link](http://shop.lenovo.com/gb/en/itemdetails/0A36319/460/5166FF91DAB5442C846A84A5FA006F9D), part no: 0A36319).

Since I had some trouble with 3G modems previously I'd like to know whether it'll work well with linux (preferably debian, without doing any magic). I tried to google it but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That FRU# 0A36319 is actually a Ericsson H5321gw card. Looking around this card does appear to be supported, but there are different revisions of the hardware and so they typically change the USB ID of the revisions slightly so you may need to add your particular version to ModemManager so that it's recognized.

- [ThinkWiki page on W530](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category%3aW530)
- [Issue with USB ID](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/1057956)

Finally [this page](https://techship.se/products/ericsson-h5321gw-101/) shows that the H5321gw carry's support for GNU Linux.

*excerpt*

```
Driver Support

Windows XP
Windows Vista
Windows 7
GNU + Linux (Patch available for kernels < 2.6.38)
Android (RIL)
MeeGo
Chrome OS
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, will be supported in ModemManager/NetworkManager, either via AT+WWAN or even via MBIM through libmbim.

ModemManager has several [H5321gw flags for different VID/PIDs](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/ModemManager/ModemManager/tree/plugins/mbm/77-mm-ericsson-mbm.rules#n35) already, but if yours end up being shown with a different pair, just [post a new bugreport](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=ModemManager) to ModemManager to get it added properly.